# Inline assembly, how to get string from struct in mapping with Yul?

Tags: mapping, struct, assembly

I don't get how to get next element in struct.
I can take id value, but what to do next?
i assume, i need to add 1 to slot, to get string value
but what it return, reference to the string? and what i should do next with that?
if i add 1 to slot, and try to sload, it out of gas

```
    struct Data {
        uint id;
        string name;
        string sername;
        uint8 status;
    }
    mapping (uint => Data) private idToData;
  
function getStructFromMapping(uint n) public view returns(uint r) {
    assembly {
        mstore(0x0, n)
        mstore(0x20, idToData.slot)
        let slot := keccak256(0x0, 0x40)
        r := sload(slot)
      }
}
```

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is pure Yul for getting fields of a struct of the `Data` type at a specific mapping key entry:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Test_Yul {
    struct Data {
        uint id;
        string name;
        string surname;
        uint8 status;
    }
    mapping (uint => Data) private idToData;

    constructor() {
        idToData[0] = Data({
            id: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935, // type(uint256).max, // testing for real uint256 values, contrary to the ones that fit in a 128-bit slot
            name: "Alice",
            surname: "Lancaster",
            status: 4
        });
    }

    /*
        The storage layout of a Data struct is the following:

        - id is the first 32-bytes slot
        - name is the second 32-bytes slot (because a string is at least 256-bits sized)
        - surname is the third 32-bytes slot (because a string is at least 256-bits sized)
        - status is a part of the fourth 32-bytes slot

        |   Name    |   Type    |   Slot №  | Bits size  |
        |:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:----------:|
        |    id     |  uint256  |    0      |    256     |
        |   name    |  string   |    1      |    256     |
        |  surname  |  string   |    2      |    256     |
        |  status   |  uint8    |    3      |     8      |
    */

    /*
        * Remember that the struct is split into 32-byte slots in memory, chained one after the other
    */

    function getValues(uint index) public view returns(uint id, string memory name, string memory surname, uint8 status){
        bytes32 nameBytes;
        bytes32 surnameBytes;
        assembly {
           mstore(0x00, index)
           mstore(0x20, idToData.slot)
           let slot := keccak256(0, 0x40)
           id := sload(slot)


           nameBytes := sload(add(slot, 1)) // we first need to store the slots №2 and №3 in bytes32 variables
           surnameBytes := sload(add(slot, 2)) // same as above

           mstore(add(name, 32), nameBytes)

           mstore(add(surname, 32), surnameBytes)
           
           let slot3 := sload(add(slot, 3))

           status := and(slot3, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

    }

    name = bytes32ToString(nameBytes);
    surname = bytes32ToString(surnameBytes);
}

function bytes32ToString(bytes32 source)
    internal
    pure
    returns (string memory result)
{
    uint8 length = 0;
    while (source[length] != 0 && length < 32) {
        length++;
    }
    assembly {
        result := mload(0x40)
        // new "memory end" including padding (the string isn't larger than 32 bytes)
        mstore(0x40, add(result, 0x40))
        // store length in memory
        mstore(result, length)
        // write actual data
        mstore(add(result, 0x20), source)
    }
}
}
```

Please see the comments in the code for more details.

**The result is:**

[image: result]

---

The only part that isn't written in Yul is the `bytes32ToString` conversion function. You could just do something like this, but you'll have empty characters, because the string will be of fixed 32-bytes length:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Test_Yul {
    struct Data {
        uint id;
        string name;
        string surname;
        uint8 status;
    }
    mapping (uint => Data) private idToData;

    constructor() {
        idToData[0] = Data({
            id: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935, // type(uint256).max, // testing for real uint256 values, contrary to the ones that fit in a 128-bit slot
            name: "Alice",
            surname: "Lancaster",
            status: 4
        });
    }

    /*
        The storage layout of a Data struct is the following:

        - id is the first 32-bytes slot
        - name is the second 32-bytes slot (because a string is at least 256-bits sized)
        - surname is the third 32-bytes slot (because a string is at least 256-bits sized)
        - status is a part of the fourth 32-bytes slot

        |   Name    |   Type    |   Slot №  | Bits size  |
        |:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:----------:|
        |    id     |  uint256  |    0      |    256     |
        |   name    |  string   |    1      |    256     |
        |  surname  |  string   |    2      |    256     |
        |  status   |  uint8    |    3      |     8      |
    */

    /*
        * Remember that the struct is split into 32-byte slots in memory, chained one after the other
    */

    function getValues(uint index) public view returns(uint id, string memory name, string memory surname, uint8 status){
        name = new string(32);
        surname = new string(32);
        assembly {
           mstore(0x00, index)
           mstore(0x20, idToData.slot)
           let slot := keccak256(0, 0x40)
           id := sload(slot)


           let nameBytes := sload(add(slot, 1)) // we first need to store the slots №2 and №3 in bytes32 variables
           let surnameBytes := sload(add(slot, 2)) // same as above

           mstore(add(name, 32), nameBytes)

           mstore(add(surname, 32), surnameBytes)
           
           let slot3 := sload(add(slot, 3))

           status := and(slot3, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

    }
}
}
```

**The result is:**

[image: result_2]